"This, I like." VS "This is what I like." — In which cases would you prefer one and in which the other?
from one of answers on english.stackexchange.com:

(1) I like this. — That focuses on the person talking.
(2) This, I like. — That focuses on the object of the statement.

my variant:
(3) This is what I like.
As far as I understand, the word order in (3) is also a way to emphasize "this".
I understand (1) is the most common variant but I'm interested to compare (2) and (3).
What's the difference between (2) and (3)?
In which cases would you prefer (2) to (3) and in which (3) to (2)?

(3) is much more idiomatic than (2). The person writing the answer was simply comparing the two different word orders.

I'd be inclined to use "this, I like" after mentioning something that I don't like. For example, on hearing something by Joss Stone (a soul musician) I might say

Soul music does nothing for me but this, I like!

By contrast, "this is what I like" can be used without reference to anything else. For example, I could be sitting outside my house with a cold beer, watching the sun set, and say

Now, this is what I like!


A person sitting on a beach chair, an alcholic fruit drink in hand, looking at a sunset over a tranquil ocean might say

This, I could get used to.

Via the emphatic placement of deictic "this", there is an unspoken allusion to all of life's trials and tribulations, the irksome, tedious, painful bits; so it's a terse, humorous form of contrast: this, unlike all the other stuff, the "that".
Compare the title of a memoir by Robert Graves: Goodbye to All That
P.S. To say "This is what ..." doesn't isolate "this" to the extent that the version without the copula isolates it. In the "This, I" version, "this" is  followed by  a marked syntactic pause which puts it more "in the spotlight". "This is what" is more clarification than exclamation.

I'm a bit confused with your example because JavaLatte in their answer says: "I'd be inclined to use "this, I like" after mentioning something that I don't like". Therefore according to this, your example "This, I could get used to" normally has to have such a context that before you said this sentence, you had thought about something you couldn't get used to. Is it so? If not, then why not? Thanks.

@Lovii I don't think you've read my answer carefully enough, as its central paragraph addresses the very point you raise in your comment above.

@Lovii: Moreover, you have drawn an unwarranted conclusion from JavaLatte's remark. His "inclination" does not mean that the locution "normally has to have such a context that before you said this sentence..."   There is a contrast involved, but it doesn't need to have been explicitly established earlier in the context.

Yes, you're right, I didn't  read your central paragraph carefully enough. The language you describe your thoughts is quite difficult. Here are four words you used which oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com doesn't mark with "A/B1/B2/C1/C2" labels: "trial" in the meaning "difficult experience", "tribulation", "irksome" and "terse". That means, your text was hard for me to understand. I reread it with a dictionary and hope now I've begun understanding it right. Anyway, thank you for help.

@Lovii Your questions often seem to be on very specific fine points of grammar, so I was not aware that your vocabulary wasn't on par with your grammatical knowledge.

Specificity of questions and volume of vocabulary don't correlate with each other. I have the memory of an average man and have no native English speakers in my surrounding verbally to talk to. So it's logical that mostly I can know only frequently-used words. As to "very specific fine points of grammar", I just enjoy to get new information about English grammar just as someone enjoys to read fiction literature or ride their bicycle. That is, the main reason I ask such questions is that I enjoy to learn English grammar and experience positive emotions when someone on forums shares it with me.
